# Grub menu appeared without configuring it

Tags: boot, grub2

I had a clean ubuntu installation on one SSD, and a clean windows installation on another SSD (two physical SSDs, not partitions). I usually switch using the bios boot menu because I spend 90% of my time on Ubuntu, and this worked for a couple of months.

However, without touching any settings, the GRUB menu appeared today on boot and let me choose between Ubuntu and Windows. I’ve got no problems with this at the moment, but I’m just curious how and why this happened?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kernel update triggers `os-prober` which in turn detected Windows and added it to the Grub menu, for your convenience, resulting in a dual-boot as it should be.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn’t aware that this could happen even if the two OSes are installed on separate SSDs, with GRUB only installed on one of the two.

Comment: Where the OSes are installed is totally irrelevant.